# Data formatting using for loops and lag function for time series with neural net

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I am looking to build a Neural network model for prediction. I am trying to get my data to be in the format that is shown in the image. I am using the lag function to lag the data for time series and also using 2 for loops to try and set up the data in this format but I am quite confused and struggling with this for sometime. How could I use 2 for loops and the lag function to set up my data like this for Neural Network prediction?

Format:
[image]

Current code:

```
data <-
  structure(
    list(
      `USD/EUR` = c(
        1.373,
        1.386,
        1.3768,
        1.3718,
        1.3774,
        1.3672,
        1.3872,
        1.3932,
        1.3911,
        1.3838,
        1.4171,
        1.4164,
        1.3947,
        1.3675,
        1.3801,
        1.3744,
        1.3759,
        1.3743,
        1.3787,
        1.3595,
        1.3599,
        1.3624,
        1.3523,
        1.3506,
        1.3521
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-25L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

#Lag the data using lag function
lagData <- c(lag(data$`USD/EUR`,k = 0))
lagData

Store <- numeric(4)
for(i in data){
  for(j in 1:4){
    Store[j] = i[j]
  }
}

Store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::lead`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    `2 days ago` = `USD/EUR`,
    `1 day ago` = lead(`USD/EUR`, n=1L),
    today = lead(`USD/EUR`, n=2L),
    predict = lead(`USD/EUR`, n=3L)
  ) %>% 
  drop_na()

df
# A tibble: 22 x 5
#    `USD/EUR` `2 days ago` `1 day ago` today predict
#        <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1      1.37         1.37        1.39  1.38    1.37
#  2      1.39         1.39        1.38  1.37    1.38
#  3      1.38         1.38        1.37  1.38    1.37
#  4      1.37         1.37        1.38  1.37    1.39
#  5      1.38         1.38        1.37  1.39    1.39
#  6      1.37         1.37        1.39  1.39    1.39
#  7      1.39         1.39        1.39  1.39    1.38
#  8      1.39         1.39        1.39  1.38    1.42
#  9      1.39         1.39        1.38  1.42    1.42
# 10      1.38         1.38        1.42  1.42    1.39
# ... with 12 more rows
```

The numbers aren't actually rounded, but just print that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use a for loop.

in base R:

```
    matrix(lag(data$`USD/EUR`), nrow = 6, byrow = TRUE)
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,]     NA 1.3730 1.3860 1.3768
[2,] 1.3718 1.3774 1.3672 1.3872
[3,] 1.3932 1.3911 1.3838 1.4171
[4,] 1.4164 1.3947 1.3675 1.3801
[5,] 1.3744 1.3759 1.3743 1.3787
[6,] 1.3595 1.3599 1.3624 1.3523
```

and then rename columns etc...

or you if you want to do it the tidyverse way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(id = sort(rep(seq(1:6), 4))) %>%  # Add ID column
  mutate(time = rep(c("2d", "1d", "today", "pred"), 6)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = `USD/EUR`)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id  `2d`  `1d` today  pred
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  1.37  1.39  1.38  1.37
2     2  1.38  1.37  1.39  1.39
3     3  1.39  1.38  1.42  1.42
4     4  1.39  1.37  1.38  1.37
5     5  1.38  1.37  1.38  1.36
6     6  1.36  1.36  1.35  1.35
```

There is also a [tidy lag function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html). FYI the data you provided is not a multiple of 4 so I deleted an observation.

Comment: @ASH I get 6 X 5 matrix using your data and matrix answer from SEcker

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a way for me to use the lag function to make the data shift like it is in the image above and then store it inside a matrix?